# Start Activity for Result Request Code in Library Project

Tags: android, android-activity, android-library, onactivityresult

I am currently working on a library project for Android which I plan on open sourcing. The library has an activity that I need to return a result for so the app that's utilising the library will need to call `startActivityForResult`.

My question is, if the user has an activity within their app, which calls a second activity within their own app which also needs to return a result, and this activity needs to call the activity from my library, my libraries activity, and their own activity will be using the same onActivityResult callback. Is there a way to avoid my activities request code, not conflicting with one of their own request codes, is it just a case of assume their own request codes are 1, 2, 3 etc and I start my libraries activity request code from some arbitrary number like 1000.

Is this just the way it works or is there a better way to avoid my request  code for my library conflicting with another apps activities request code?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the situation: you have an Activity A in your library which has to implement/ call startActivityForResult(), maybe to let the user pick a photo, and this Activity A implements onActivityResult() to do something with the resulting data. You are concerned that if some other Activity B uses the same request code because it has some kind of request for your Activity A, then there might be some kind of problem. Did I get it right?

Comment: Not quite, the users app, has activity a, my library has activity b. Activity A calls startActivityForResult to activity b, and activity b sends the result back to activity a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the library should give a parameter to specify request code by developer themselves for startActivityForResult, so they could never be conflicted in the same activity or fragment they have been called from.

Comment: When you say should give a parameter, do you mean by using putExtra on the intent object?

Comment: Yes, you can ask the developer to putExtra and pass the resultcode and retrieve it in your library by getIntExtra

Comment: Yea that does sound like a good idea. I think I'll do it that way. Cheers

Comment: great, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

`Activity` A can choose its own request codes, and `Activity` B will never know which request code is used by A.

Which is no problem because request codes are purely local. Each `Activity` instance is separate from other `Activity` instances - they won't be mixed up just because they all implement the same method (like `onCreate()` or in your case `onActivityResult()` ).

Let's take a look at some lines from the [source code for android.app.Activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java), starting at line 4614

```
public void startActivityForResult(@RequiresPermission Intent intent, int requestCode,
        @Nullable Bundle options) {
    if (mParent == null) {
        options = transferSpringboardActivityOptions(options);
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
            mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
                this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
                intent, requestCode, options);
        if (ar != null) {
            mMainThread.sendActivityResult(
                mToken, mEmbeddedID, requestCode, ar.getResultCode(),
                ar.getResultData());
        }
        if (requestCode >= 0) {
            // If this start is requesting a result, we can avoid making
            // the activity visible until the result is received.  Setting
            // this code during onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) or onResume() will keep the
            // activity hidden during this time, to avoid flickering.
            // This can only be done when a result is requested because
            // that guarantees we will get information back when the
            // activity is finished, no matter what happens to it.
            mStartedActivity = true;
        }
        cancelInputsAndStartExitTransition(options);
        // TODO Consider clearing/flushing other event sources and events for child windows.
    } else {
        if (options != null) {
            mParent.startActivityFromChild(this, intent, requestCode, options);
        } else {
            // Note we want to go through this method for compatibility with
            // existing applications that may have overridden it.
            mParent.startActivityFromChild(this, intent, requestCode);
        }
    }
}
```

The comments in the quoted code snippet show that the request code is used to determine if there is a result to be returned.

Please note that the parameters for `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)` are passed into a method `execStartActivity()` from the `Instrumentation` class in the same package *android.app*.

But there are four other parameters to `execStartActivity()` which serve to identify the calling app and the current `Activity` instance (I won't go into details of the Binder framework here, but there is for example [a youtube video](https://youtu.be/Jgampt1DOak) on this topic):

```
Context who, IBinder contextThread, IBinder token, Activity target
```

Again, the request code is only used to determine if there is a result to be returned (for a negative request code, `startActivityForResult()` is handled just like `startActivity()`)

```
return requestCode >= 0 ? am.getResult() : null;
```

Besides that, the request code is just passed back to the `Activity` which called `startActivityForResult()`.

So if an `Activity` doesn't use the same request code for different types of requests, all is good.